# How can I bypass an elder vampire's Fortitude?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

I am fighting a 6th Gen with Fortitude 4. I am a 13th Gen with one discipline at rank 5 (Thaumaturgy) Blood path. I have some good stats for my occult and intelligence, but the problem is the character is the DMs baby in a way (as well as being a sixth gen), but unfortunately he forced my character into having a serious vengeance streak against him and I can't see my character letting it go.

I don't know enough about the system to really get the advantage in my favor, but any advice on either what I can do with Blood path that I didn't think of, Good combinations with other level one disciplines, or just a good trick to kill him.

Is there any means to bypass Fortitude on a vampire, besides just throwing damage at him? And if that is the only way, what are the best ways to do it?

Answer (score 17):

First off: The Discipline Fortitude can't be bypassed. At least not that I know of. It's the only way for a vampire to soak aggravated damage, and not even a reliable one. So the only way to outright kill him, is to throw punches at him. Take Path of Blood 5 and burn his blood.

Another way would be to let him burn his own blood until he is in frenzy. He won't have that much Blood left to boost his physical traits or use Celerity or other Disciplines. It's way too risky I'd say, but it is a way to deal with him.

But for goodness sake you're playing a Tremere not a Brujah or Gangrel. You're taking the wrong approach to this problem. You're a social clan, so to speak. You have a tight-knit clan and you should have friends. You can ask your superiors to teach you a new Ritual. (Sorry that I can't tell you which one to pick, I don't know them all)

A sixth generation vampire may be immune to your Dominate but if you have a Toreador or Ventrue with you he isn't immune to their Presence. That might cost you some favours but can help you defeating him.

Another possibility is to let him make a fool of himself in front of the whole domain. It sure as hell will make your unlife way more difficult but when done correctly you not only have a hell of character play, be much more satisfied with yourself, but also you'll get some new Allies. You'll get some new Enemies, of course, but did you want to play a vampire without having enemies?

My best advice for you is to not take this enemy head on. If you want to destroy him do it slowly and with a Masterplan. Of course that is difficult but it's the best way to deal with such an enemy. If it's a Gangrel you just can't take him head on. He'll kill you within the first two seconds of the fight. If it's a Ventrue or Ravnos (all assuming he has Fortitude as clan discipline) then it's going to just take two minutes to kill your vampire.
So "just" take it slowly and (for instance) find (or create) some evidences that he wanted to overthrow the Prince (or if he's the Prince that he wanted to disband the Primogen Council) and perhaps he's got a Blood Hunt waiting for him.

If for any reason all your plans are being thwarted and he's still on top, you should perhaps talk to your DM about that particular character of his.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to use the brain. I won't put a new answer, but I will add to yours that he can also use smart but violent solutions. I.e. investigate where his haven is (maybe there are rituals that help here), then hire some criminals to burn it to the ground during the day. No Fortitude can save you from this.

Comment: +1 for avoiding direct violent confrontation. Never meat an enemy on his terrain. But I'd say that the Tremere is more mental than social clan: many are nerds and anyway it's the most distrusted clan in Camarilla (with reason).

Comment: Agreeing with both of the above! Not only are you Camarilla, but Camarilla Tremere. Be crafty, not savage.

Comment: A million upvotes if I could. _Vampire: The Masquerade_ is a game of politics and intrigue, the splattered blood is just set dressing.

Answer (score 16):

You're already in pretty good shape: Thaumaturgy is, by default, not resisted by Fortitude. What's more, even though **Cauldron of Blood** allows Fortitude to defend against the damage, it's *just* the levels in Fortitude that get rolled, not the 6th-Gen's elder-level Stamina plus Fortitude. Four dice to defend against aggravated damage isn't so great for him. You can also use **Theft of Vitae** to steal his blood before he can use it.

I'll caution you, though, that your die pool here is not Intelligence + Occult; it's your Willpower, difficulty 8. [p.213] Intelligence + Occult is to enact Thaumaturgical Rituals.

Speaking of, you have Thaum 5, which means you have access to five-dot Rituals. **Paper Flesh** [p.240] is one such ritual, and that would reduce your Sixth Gen opponent to a Stamina + Fortitude total of no more than 4. (STA 1, FOR 3)

Comment: I hope he also has some way to not die in the first two exchanges though...

Comment: @C.Ross The greater issue of "how do I, as a neonate, not die in a physical fight against an elder vampire" is beyond the scope of this answer. :)

Comment: Jadasc, it certainly is, but it may well be a bigger problem.

Comment: @Flamma That's true, too, although blood denial is a strategy that works remarkably well on elders, too. Healing agg in combat isn't really a viable choice, so I'll amend the entry to reflect that.

Comment: "You can also use Theft of Vitae to steal his blood before he can use it". Yeah, that seems a very good reason. I delete my previous comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

A 6th gen elder is a formidable foe. I would think the 4 dots in fortitude would be the least of your worries. If nothing else, a 6th gen vampire can spend 6 blood points a turn, which means he can easily punch you with strength 10 in the blink of an eye. As a lowly 13th gen, you only get to spend 1 blood point a turn.

Your best option is to lay low and wait for the right opportunity to strike. Keep your eyes open and use your head, not everything needs to be solved by violence. For example, if you find out where his haven is, you can arrange a tip-off to the Sabbat.

Another option is to align yourself with another powerful elder. Elders always have enemies, and if you make yourself useful enough, your enemy's enemy might want to work with you. The upside is that you'll have more chances to strike at your enemy. The downside is that you'll likely be used as a pawn and discarded when you're no longer useful.

If none of the options above appeal to you, then you can always plant a bomb on his car. Fortitude 4 is not going to help against 15 dies of aggravated damage.

Answer (score 0):

Fortitude is a Discipline that grants Kindred unearthly toughness, even to the point of resisting fire and sunlight. Normally Fortitude does not need to be activated, and each dot is added to all soak rolls.  That is the definition of White-Wolf present in it´s wiki (http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Fortitude)

I don´t see any trick like aiming an arrow for the eye because eye does not have fortitude...Fortitude is very well definided and generalist at the same time.  What I would do to be successful against some tuff guy with fortitude is to deal damages only soakable with fortitude rolls (rolling only the dots in Fortitude).

Taking your character as an example, you could use Theft of Vitae to steal blood from your victm and then, next turn if you survive the attack, use that blood to increase your stats, specially Dexterity and Stamina.

Next turn you may try to touch him or take a defensive instance and wait for the attack comes, either way you must try to touch him and use Cauldrom of Blood to vaporize his blood and cause aggravated damage only soakable with fortitude.  That is why you boost up Dexterity and Stamina.  If you have at least 2 success you will have a advantage of -1 on the victim's dice pool.

Other variations could be useful, like using Blood Shield.  But the kernell of the strategy would be Cauldron of blood.

Other situations, not applyable to your case, are use Celerity and Potency with Claws to deal lots of damage in a repeated way.

Well, this is just one suggestion.